# apc.filters by path?

Tags: php, apc, opcode-cache

How would I use the apc.filters parameter in APC opcode caching to not cache certain paths? For example, I want caching to be active for anything under the path:

"/var/www/vhosts"

and exclude paths like

"/usr/share/psa-horde/"

I tried using

```
apc.cache_by_default = 0
apc.filters = "+/var/www/vhosts"
```

and

```
apc.cache_by_default = 1
apc.filters = "-/usr/share/psa-horde/"
```

But neither worked as I expected.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.filters

Should the filter be something more like "+/var/www/vhosts/*" (note the wildcard)? I'm afraid this isn't possible because of the way filters works:

> Note that the filename used for
>   matching is the one passed to
>   include/require, not the absolute
>   path.

Any ideas or sample configurations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filter should be a comma separated list of POSIX extended regular expressions. I believe what you have in the second attempt only matches the exact path /usr/share/psa-horde/, and not /usr/share/psa-horde/something or /usr/share/psa-horde/anotherfile.php

The following should match anything in the sub folder

```
apc.filters = "-/usr/share/psa-horde/.*"
```

Comment: Hmm, good call, but I think it only works for the file name if the full path was used in the require statement: "Note that the filename used for matching is the one passed to include/require, not the absolute path."

Comment: e.g. tried "-/var/www/vhosts/myhostname.com/svn/public/openx/.*" and files in this directory are still being cached.

Comment: "Note that the filename used for matching is the one passed to include/require, not the absolute path." - from docs

Comment: I don't understand this exact phrase.. what path should he use instead of "-/var/www/vhosts/myhostname.com/svn/public/openx/.*" ?

Answer (score 5):

A very late response, but just in case someone else is having this issue (I'm going to guess you may be/have been running a Plesk box, which is why I came across this).

Your best bet is to have APC in the list of loaded php modules, but have
`apc.enabled 0` in the master php.ini.  Then, for each vhost you want to have it enabled for, add `php_admin_value apc.enabled 1` to enable for each.  Could be an issue if you have a ton of sites, but works for just a few.

Answer (score 2):

pnomolos' solution works if you have different vhosts, but it won't work if you have only one and want to control caching on a truly per-directory basis.

This bug report points to the best the solution : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57064

Enable APC and set `apc.cache_by_default` to `0` in `php.ini`. In your Apache config, you can then use `php_admin_setting apc.cache_by_default 1` inside a `Directory` block to enable APC caching exactly where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Since apc.filters works with regular expressions, wildcard path should be specified as
apc.filters = "-/usr/share/psa-horde/.*"

Answer (score 0):

Used:

```
apc.filters="-/eliminate/path1/,-/eliminate/path2/,+/add/to/cache/"
```