# php apc.filters syntax

Tags: php, apc

I am having trouble understanding the format required by the apc.filters directive in PHP APC configuration. (particularly for more than one patterns)

The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.filters) says
"A comma-separated list of POSIX extended regular expressions."

Let's say i **don't** want to cache two files namely brooklyn.php and boston.php

I put the following entry:

`apc.filters = "-(.*)/brooklyn\.php$, -(.*)/boston\.php$"`

It still caches

I also tried

`apc.filters = "-(.*)/brooklyn\.php$", "-(.*)/boston\.php$"`

Still caches

I would really appreciate if someone could write a sample expression that has multiple patterns.

Comment: I know it's a old question, but could you confirm if you have found a solution or any of the answers work?

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't this do the trick?

```
apc.filters = "-/brooklyn\.php$,-/boston\.php$"
```

or

```
apc.filters = "-/(brooklyn|boston)\.php$"
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't wait to see if you get any answers. I could never get the "dis-include" to work (my related question: [apc.filters by path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626262/apc-filters-by-path)) Only worked for me by turning off `cache_by_default` and +ing instead of -ing paths.

Comment: Yep, I had to do this too. :(

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem and finally found the way to go.
You just have to remove spaces after each comma.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
apc.filters = "brooklyn.php$,boston.php$"
```